# Do QFTs with a physical cut-off not respect the postulates of Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, hilbert-space, effective-field-theory

Wilsonian renormalization says that it's fine to have a physical cut-off. But I am thinking that such theories do not respect the postulates of Quantum Mechanics. Is this true?

Theories with a physical cut-off $\Lambda$ describe a state $|\psi\rangle$ in the Hilbert space of **wavefunctionals**. So far, so good.

But the **time evolution** of this state is supposed to be a path integral over **all** intermediate states. Each basis state in the Hilbert space, i.e. each 3D field configuration must count as an intermediate state. However, theories with a physical cut off **do not** respect this postulate, because **these theories ban the high energy configurations in their path integral definition.**

This makes it look like we're modifying a QM postulate in an **ad-hoc** way. This shouldn't have worked because the path integral evolution postulate is intimately tied to other alternative postulates like the Schrodinger equation (which is synonymous with the unitarity of the theory), or the Moyal bracket from phase space QM.

**Nevertheless**, effective theories produce the correct predictions, so there must be some justification of this. One answer can be that there may exist an underlying non-field theory which obeys the QM postulates, from which the field theories may be derived. But this answer would be speculation. This would also imply that QFTs are not consistent Quantum Theories by themselves. **Are the field theories with a physical cut-off on a solid mathematical foundation or not?**

Comment: Of course EFTs are valid quantum mechanical theories -- not integrating over some modes in the path integral is equivalent to just not including them in the Hilbert space. Lattice QCD is a very concrete example of a QFT with a cutoff, which is nevertheless completely well-defined, so that you can simulate it on a computer.

Comment: This sounds like a classic case of "physics is not mathematics".  We care about the result more than the strict mathematical rigor.  Rigor has it's uses but it doesn't always allow a practical usable result to be developed.

Comment: @knzhou So, we should be thinking of QFT as "QM with a countably infinite number of lattice variables?"? I'm still not sure how this works. In the path integral, we place a restriction on the four-frequency of the path. But the Hilbert space only as 3D configurations, so you can't impose that restriction on the Hilbert space.

Comment: @knzhou Also, we can't lattci-fy the time-dimension. That would be against a QM postulate.

Comment: Just a remark: in condensed matter field theories necessarily have cut-offs, while exploiting the full (available) Hilbert space. If I am not mistaken, it was crystal lattice that inspired lattice field theories in QFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the cutoff-scheme, it's easier/harder to convince yourself that there are no problems. Easiest cutoff to consider is a lattice-cutoff, where you discretise space onto a $L^3$ grid (but leave time continuous). This is sometimes called the 'Hamiltonian formalism'. In this case, you have:

- A UV cutoff given by $|p| < \frac{\pi}{a}$, set by the physical lattice spacing $a$.
- A IR cutoff given by $|p| > \frac{\pi}{aL}$, set by the physical width of the box your theory lives in. (You can remove this IR cutoff if you want by taking the box length $L \to \infty$. Correlation functions $\langle \phi(x) \phi(y) \rangle$ for fixed $x,y$ will remain constant in this limit)
- A completely formally well-defined, finite-dimensional hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, as well as a hamiltonian operator $H$. The dimension of the hilbert space will generically scale like $d^{L^3}$ where $d$ is how many degrees of freedom you have per-site.

An example that is talked about a lot is the [Kogut-Susskind](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevD.11.395) Hamiltonian formulation of lattice-QCD.

Comment: I don't understand that, in the Wilsonian path integral, the cut off condition is written as $p^2<\Lambda$. This is a restriction on the norm of the four-frequency of the fields in the path integral. So, this puts no restriction on the 3-frequency of the 3D wavefunctionals on the Hilbert space.

Comment: @RyderRude yes, my answer is specific to lattice regularization (which is a particular physical cutoff), where it is clear what can be formally stated. I don't know if the picture is so clear for hard cutoffs like $p^2 < \Lambda$ in minkowski space - I don't know if *anyone* can write down the interacting hilbert space (with or without cutoff) for all but the simplest of theories, in the continuum.